# Como crear un arreglo con la misma clave en angular

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7

necesito un arreglo con este formato

```
"Documento":[
    {"documento":"11111"},
    {"documento":"22222"}
]
```

declaro el arreglo

```
documentos: {[key: string]: string} ={};
```

y lo lleno

```
this.documentos["documento"] = 11111;
this.documentos["documento"] = 22222;
```

pero  de esta forma me sobrescribe el valor de la clave

```
"Documento":[
    {"documento":"22222"},
```

Angular

Comment: Estás declarando _documentos_ como objeto `{}` y no como arreglo `[]`. Cambia la declaración `documentos: [];` y no uses índices, simplemente inserta cada nuevo elemento: `this.documentos.push(11111);`

Comment: no me sirve de esa forma por que  necesito asegurar  que ese arreglo quede de la  forma  {
    "Documento":[
        {"documento":"7777"},
        {"documento":"22222"}
    ],
    "IdAplicacion":1
} para poder enviarlo al backend

Comment: Entonces debería ser algo como Declarar: `documentos: {"Documentos": []};` Agregar: `this.documentos["Documentos"].push({"documento": 11111});`

Comment: No funciono me trae el siguiente error  Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'Documentos' of undefined

Comment: Entonces la definición de `documentos` no es correcta o está en un contexto diferente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya que estas usando **TS** con **Angular** seria bueno que primero declares tu interfaz para que no te pierdas al momento de insertar nuevos documentos como se ve en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
export interface Documento {
  IdAplicacion: number;
  Documentos: Array < {
    documento: string
  } >;
}
```

Ahora tienes que declarar tu variable, lo tipas con tu interfaz y lo inicializas:

```
public documentos: Documento[] = [];
```

Para añadir un documento a tu array de Documentos tendrias que usar la funcion **push** y para seguir añadiendo posteriormente Documentos sobre un Documento en especifico tienes que especificar la posicion donde se encuentra.

```
this.documentos.push({
  IdAplicacion: 1,
  Documentos: [{
    documento: '1111'
  }]
});

this.documentos[0].Documentos.push({
  documento: '2222'
});
```

Para finalizar seria bueno que el **IdAplicacion** se refleje en la posicion de tu array con el fin de poder añadir facilmente nuevos Documentos.

```
this.documentos[IdAplicacion].Documentos.push({
  documento: '2222'
});
```